# Play FLV videos in mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

How can I do to play .FLV videos in mediaelement.js ?

It's for a internal applicatoin, and I need to play only MP4 and FLV videos using Google Chrome and mediaelement.js

Answer (score 9):

Just insert `<video src="path/to/myvideo.flv" id="myvideo" controls="controls" preload="true"></video>` in your code and instantiate a mediaelement object out of the video's id.